# How to find whether system has the font I needed in MFC?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, fonts, system

I want to write the following function

```
bool IsFontExistInSystem(const CString& fontStyle) const
{

}
```

Is there any API in windows to do this?
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some old code I dug out that will check if a font is installed.  It could do with being tidied up but you get the idea:

```
static int CALLBACK CFontHelper::EnumFontFamExProc(ENUMLOGFONTEX* /*lpelfe*/, NEWTEXTMETRICEX* /*lpntme*/, int /*FontType*/, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPARAM* l = (LPARAM*)lParam;
    *l = TRUE;
    return TRUE;
}

bool Font::IsInstalled(LPCTSTR lpszFont)
{
    // Get the screen DC
    CDC dc;
    if (!dc.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL))
    {
        return false;
    }
    LOGFONT lf = { 0 };
    // Any character set will do
    lf.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    // Set the facename to check for
    _tcscpy(lf.lfFaceName, lpszFont);
    LPARAM lParam = 0;
    // Enumerate fonts
    ::EnumFontFamiliesEx(dc.GetSafeHdc(), &lf,  (FONTENUMPROC)EnumFontFamExProc, (LPARAM)&lParam, 0);
    return lParam ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`EnumFontFamiliesEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162620%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find whether exist actual font.

UPD: I've just learned that it is recommended by MS to use EnumFontFamiliesEx instead of EnumFontFamilies.

Comment: I hate it when you beat me. :[

Comment: @GMan, it is a symmetric process :)

Comment: Actually, I think this function can return data, simply instead of provide a call_back function...Why dose the engineer give such a simple question complex design.... It is not comvenient to use at all.